# Select statement should return only one record

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to fetch and print only one record from database mysql.

```
#Select backlogs
{
        my $backlog_req = "select id, name, startDate, endDate, parent_id " .
                                                " from backlogs " ;
                                               "where backlogtype='Iteration' and id = $iteration" ;
print "ITERATION_ID : " . $iteration . "\n";
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $backlog_req );
        $sth->execute() ;
        $sth->bind_columns( undef, \$backlog_id, \$bl_name, \$bl_sd, \$bl_ed, \$prod_id ) ;
        while( $sth->fetch() ) {
                $Backlogs->{ $backlog_id } = { name => $bl_name, start_date => substr($bl_sd, 0, 10), end_date => substr($bl_ed, 0, 10) } ;
                print "$bl_name ($backlog_id): $bl_sd -> $bl_ed\n";
        }
```

this returns all the rows with Iteration as backlogtype. I want only backlogtype as Iteration and Id which i am providing through command line argument. as i specified in where.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
" from backlogs " ;
```

to this:

```
" from backlogs " .
```

to include the `WHERE`-clause in your query.

Also, you should add `use warnings;` to the start of your script. It would have warned you about this (by complaining that your `WHERE`-clause-only statement was a `Useless use of string in void context`).